# Python / Pandas - Pivot on multidimensional data

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, reshape

I'm new to python/pandas. I'm trying to transpose rows to columns.Apologies for any misunderstanding
[input_df(pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COSqn.jpg)
[output_df(pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ULYh.jpg)

```
input_df:
Date    Project    Processes                Time_in_sec Time_measures
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
7/6/2017    FE      eBanking .aspx          157         Average Response Time 
9/2/2017    PCB     eBanking Frontpage.fi   227         Call per hour
1/23/2017   ICC     Acct Transfer.dc        28          Average Response Time 
1/24/2017   PCB     Transaction .com        0           Number of calls
1/23/2017   ICC     eBanking Logon.no       0           Number of calls

output_df:
Date    Project Processes   Average Response Time   Call per hour   Number of calls
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
7/6/2017    FE  eBanking .aspx        157       
9/2/2017    PCB eBanking Frontpage.fi                    227    
1/24/2017   PCB Transaction .com                                        0
1/23/2017   ICC Acct Transfer.dc      28        
1/23/2017   ICC eBanking Logon.no                                       0
```

I tried the below code and got only 3 Columns 'Average Response Time','Call per hour'   'Number of calls' in the output [below_code's_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqv7a.jpg). But I'm confused how to get all the necessary 6 columns. Could you please help?

```
    output_df = input_df.pivot(columns = 'Time_measures',  values= 'Time_in_sec')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC You can using `pivot_table` with `reset_index`

```
df.pivot_table(columns='Time_measures', values='Time_in_sec',index=['Date','Project','Processes'],fill_value='').reset_index()
Out[98]: 
Time_measures       Date Project              Processes  \
0              1/23/2017     ICC       Acct Transfer.dc   
1              1/23/2017     ICC      eBanking Logon.no   
2              1/24/2017     PCB       Transaction .com   
3               7/6/2017      FE         eBanking .aspx   
4               9/2/2017     PCB  eBanking Frontpage.fi   
Time_measures Average Response Time  Call per hour Number of calls  
0                                 28                                
1                                                                0  
2                                                                0  
3                                157                                
4                                              227
```

Comment: @Tad if this is what you need , can you consider accept it ?

Comment: Accepted now :) . I'm new to stackwkf was searching for accept option :-)